# How to clear VPN saved credentials

Tags: password, vpn, openvpn

Ubuntu 18.04 OpenVPN has an option to save user name and password upon connecting to a VPN server. After that, subsequent VPN connects will skip the credential prompt.

The problem comes when the credentials have changed. If the account password is changed for example, Ubuntu will try multiple times before it fails with an error (invalid password). By this time, the account very well might have been disabled for too many bad password attempts.

In the Ubuntu 18.04 UI, there is no obvious option to clear the saved credentials.

What's the method for clearing saved VPN credentials?

Comment: There is no "Ubuntu VPN" as far as I'm aware. What VPN provider are you using and how did you configure it?

Comment: Updated above - OpenVPN

Comment: This link might help?   At the vpn-secrets?   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421452/where-does-gnome-network-manager-store-passwords  At:  "/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ directory, here all the connection details are saved.
"

Comment: You still didn't explain what VPN you are using and how you connect to it. In case you use the Network Manager page in Settings, you can open and edit VPN connections from there, including changing login credentials.

Comment: There is no option in Network Manager page to change login credentials. Options are about sharing VPN with other accounts, another tab for connection settings (protocol, gateway, certs, scripts, special authentication), and IPv4/v6 setup. The VPN secrets path listed by William above is where the VPN settings can be found, and it's possible to hand-edit the corresponding VPN settings file, and change the account name to prevent OpenVPN from using it and cached password automatically.